# how to pass parameter to javascript in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I need to pass an url from asp.net load_page to flowplayer javascript function here:
http://flowplayer.org/plugins/streaming/rtmp.html

How to do that ?

Comment: Well, you're missing a few steps between asp.net and JavaScript (namely, a web server and a client). What do you have so far?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can pass a value from ASP.NET to javascript like this:

In your page's code-behind create a property:

```
protected string MyValue { get { return "my value"; } }
```

In the markup, assign the value to a javascript variable:

```
<script>
var myValue = "<%= MyValue %>";
...
</script>
```

Now you can use this value in javascript.

Comment: This is how I do it most of the time.

Comment: Thanks that seems simple enough, I'll try.

Answer (score 1):

C#

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "_MyStartupJS", "JavaScriptFunctionNameToCall(param1Value, param2Value); ", true);
```