# How to Pass QueryString in window.location.href?

Tags: javascript

I have written the following javascript function

```
function getval(sel)
 {
    window.location.href = "Posts?Category=<%= sel %>";
 }
```

but the value of sel variable is not considered in querystring..

Instead of it, it takes value like following.

...../Post/Posts?Category=%3C%=%20sel%20%%3E

Can anyone help me???

Comment: Because `.js` files are not parsed by your back-end.

Comment: Do you really need to wrap 'sel' in `<%= %>`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to pass parameter to javascript in asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2484498/how-to-pass-parameter-to-javascript-in-asp-net)

Comment: Or would you want to use the the function argument `sel` to call a method on the back-end? In that case the principle applied is the same as http://stackoverflow.com/q/13840429/1331430

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because javascript does not understands jsp scriptlet,

Try,

```
window.location.href = "Posts?Category=" + sel;
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know where you found this `<%= sel %>`, but its not the native JavaScript style of doing it.  Try this:

```
function getval(sel)
{
    window.location.href = "Posts?Category=" + sel;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks.. This will help me in my development

Comment: how to get the Category value in Posts.html?

Comment: @Sujay What do you mean?